# Comparing geospatials paths with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am storing user travelling paths like this

[ { _id: 5336041835cd4c981c000008,
    __v: 0,
    loc: { type: 'LineString', coordinates: [ [55.195538, 25.110762], [55.407583, 25.164881] ] } },
  { _id: 5336041835cd4c981c000007,
    __v: 0,
    loc: { type: 'LineString', coordinates: [ [55.194096, 25.095051], [55.407583, 25.164881] ] } } ]

Now I would like to compare path and get the list of paths that are exactly same to provided path or nearby 100 meter for that I am using this query

db.userPaths.find( { loc :
                         { $near :
                           { $geometry :
                              { type : "LineString" ,
                                coordinates : [[ 55.194096 , 25.095051], [55.407583, 25.164881] ] ] } ,
                                $maxDistance : 100
                      } } } )

but unfortunately I am not getting anything. Am I doing it in a right manner or is there is some other way of doing it I have spent a whole day to find out a way of doing this but no luck :( Can you please help me to sort out this issue?